# Jasmine + Karma + AngularJS Router test - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$state.href') angularJS testing the router

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have error TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$state.href') but couldn't figure out what was the problem.
Here is my router

```
angular.module('ps.auth')
  .config(function ($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('login', {
      url: '/login/:username',
      views: {
        'content': {
          templateUrl: 'auth/login.html',
          controller: 'AuthController'
        }
      },
      authNotRequired: true
    })
    .state('logout', {
        url: '/logout',
        controller: 'LogoutCtrl',
        authNotRequired: true
    });
  });
```

and here is my unit test

```
'use strict';
describe('router  check', function() {
  describe('router check login', function() {
    var view = 'auth/login.html',
      myUserName = 'userName',
      state = 'login',
      $state, $templateCache;

    beforeEach(function() {
      module('ps.auth');

      inject(function(_$state_, _$templateCache_) {
        $state = _$state_;
        $templateCache = _$templateCache_;
      });

      $templateCache.put(view, '');
      $state.go('login');
      $state.$apply();
    });

    it('should map state login to url /login ', function() {
      console.log('********** My State $state = ', $state);
      expect($state.href(state, { username: myUserName})).toEqual('/login/userName');
      // expect($state.href('login', {})).toEqual('#/login');
    });
  });
});
```

Error message returns back is : TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$state.href')

Please help if you know the answer to this question

Comment: Any suggestion how to fix this issue ?

Comment: what does $state look like in the console.log?